# Python PyWin32 send keys to DirectX game in the background

Tags: python, pywin32, roblox

I have made a script that can send keys to any app in the background, but it does not work on DirectX.

I am trying to make my character jump in a game called "roblox".

This is the script

```
import time
import psutil
import win32con
from win32 import win32gui
from win32 import win32api
from win32 import win32process

keyDict = {" ": 0x20}
for i in range(0x41, 0x5A+1):
    keyDict[chr(i)] = i

def CloseExe(exeName):
    ID2Handle={}
    def get_all_hwnd(hwnd,mouse):
      if win32gui.IsWindow(hwnd) and win32gui.IsWindowEnabled(hwnd) and win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        nID=win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
        del nID[0]
        for abc in nID:
          try:
            pro=psutil.Process(abc).name()
          except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
            pass
          else:
            if pro == exeName:
                     win32gui.PostMessage(hwnd,win32con.WM_CLOSE,0,0)

    win32gui.EnumWindows(get_all_hwnd, 0)

def SendKeysSensitive(exeName, keysToSend):
    mID2Handle={}
    def get_all_hwnd(hwnd,mouse):
      hwndTwo = win32gui.GetWindow(hwnd, win32con.GW_CHILD)
      if win32gui.IsWindow(hwnd) and win32gui.IsWindowEnabled(hwnd) and win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        nID=win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
        del nID[0]
        for abc in nID:
          try:
            pro=psutil.Process(abc).name()
          except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
            pass
          else:
            if pro == exeName:
                for key in keysToSend:
                     win32gui.PostMessage(hwndTwo, win32con.WM_CHAR, key, 0)

def SendKeys(exeName, keysToSend):
    mID2Handle={}
    def get_all_hwnd(hwnd,mouse):
      hwndTwo = hwnd
      if win32gui.IsWindow(hwnd) and win32gui.IsWindowEnabled(hwnd) and win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        nID=win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
        del nID[0]
        for abc in nID:
          try:
            pro=psutil.Process(abc).name()
          except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
            pass
          else:
            if pro == exeName:
                for key in keysToSend:
                     win32gui.PostMessage(hwndTwo, win32con.WM_CHAR, key, 0)

    win32gui.EnumWindows(get_all_hwnd, 0)


def TranslateKeys(text):
    outKeys = []
    for char in text:
        outKeys.append(keyDict.get(char.upper()))
    return outKeys

def ExE(name):
    return name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    prog = ExE("RobloxPlayerBeta.exe")
    jump = TranslateKeys(" ")
    SendKeys(prog, jump)
```

It does not work due to "RobloxPlayerBeta.exe" being DirectX.

I can not open the app, it 100% needs to be in the background.

Is this possible?

Comment: Anyone? If its impossible at least tell me

Answer (score 0):

Well I had a problem similar to this and I found a solution. I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but there is a library for sending input to DirectX applications

It's called [PyDirectInput](https://pypi.org/project/PyDirectInput/). It's essentially PyAutoGui but works with DirectX

> pip install pydirectinput

As far as roblox, I have used this before and can say it does work.

[source code](https://github.com/learncodebygaming/pydirectinput/blob/master/pydirectinput/__init__.py)

Comment: Thanks, however I stated "I can not open the app, it 100% needs to be in the background."